# How to save a SATA HDD with a broken data connector?

Tags: hard-drive, sata, cable, connector, defective-hardware

While reconfiguring my home server, I discovered why my data drive isn't detected anymore:
[image]

This is an expensive 6-terabyte drive. I'm not asking *whether* it can be salvaged, I'm asking **how?**

I can think of a few ways, but please help me choose the one with the highest chance of success! I'm very open to better ideas of course:

- Carefully try to plug it back in, then use epoxy to keep it in place. Afraid that the connectors won't touch well, or bend the leads. This is a one-shot chance.
- Cut the cable open to salvage the broken off connector, then use instant glue(?) to put it back in place to connect a new cable. Afraid that glueing that tiny bit of plastic isn't going to be reliable enough for use.
- Cut off the blocked cable end and then solder the cable leads directly onto the connector leads. Best chance of electrical connection, but requires delicate work. (I'm good with soldering, and I have heatshrinks.)

I have seen [this similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/367719/how-do-i-connect-a-hard-drive-with-a-broken-sata-connector) and I see that glueing helped him, but I can't tell from the page whether his situation was really similar. Also, the external USB dock is a nice try but not reliable and not suited as permanent solution.

I am aware that I need to be ultra careful with this weak spot in the future. I don't like this situation, but I have to deal with it.

Answer (score 3):

I knew someone salvaged a drive by taking a SATA cable, stripping off one end, and soldered the cable directly to the plug.  The drive worked, but he didn't keep using it.  It was just an experiment.

This was one of the suggestion you listed, but I can confirm that it really will work.  It'll give you the most reliable way of accessing the data, since the other methods of repair will be unreliable at best.

Comment: I'd be suggesting the same thing in this case... tin the pins and then get a blank sata and solder to the existing pins.

Comment: The only sensible solution!

Comment: I would also wrap the cable around and attach it to the housing of the drive, so that the mechanical force on the cable isn't forwarded to the pins ("cable relief"). This drive could run for years if it hasn't fallen on the floor... only the connector was broken.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: Being expensive is no technical property. Be prepared for this drive to fail again, don't put anything important on it.

Now: Your second options seems the one with the best ration of success likelyhood vs. hassle:

- it doesn't block you from falling back top the third option
- glued plastic is actually quite strong

Comment: ad *expensive*, I needed to mention this because I am not going to spend hundreds of bucks on a new drive. I'm on a budget here. Ad *Be prepared for this drive to fail again* I only agree insofar as the connector is concerned; the rest of the drive is still basically brand new.

Answer (score 0):

Option #1 probably won't work, you'll bend the pins with the cable header which is still inside the broken off part. Try pulling that part off with a flat screwdriver, then carefully put it back on the drive and fix with super glue. A few pointers:

- Avoid cheap glues and "super-gel" glues
- Avoid touching the crack surface with your fingers, you'll get water and grease in there.
- Even if the super glue holds stuff in place in seconds, let it dry for several hours (I'd suggest a day) before attempting to plug the cable back.

Should this fail, #3 will still be an option.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the drive type, size and how bad the damage is, there are a couple of options that are more permanent.

One of them is to find on eBay or elsewhere a compatible PCB for your drive (there is a part number etched onto the PCB). swap out the old with the new. If the data is not important, then a new drive may be cheaper in many cases.

The second option is to replace the entire sata/sas connector on the drive for a new one. you can buy them online like on alibaba... or you can get them from dead drives. SAS drive connectors are similar, but not the same... so make sure you get the correct type for yours.

Soldering skills will be required, but this is the preferred method I currently use and even though it is time consuming (specially waiting for the parts), I have had great success with it, so far.

But, McGivering the connector to a cable is also a good enough solution. Gluing to a very thin piece of plastic could help keep the pins aligned.... or solder the cable directly to the PCB.